# Best way to set default value for javabean

Tags: java, java-8

I has a javabean like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private String bar;

    ...getter/setter...

}
```

Then I want to set value like this:

```
if (foo.getBar() == null) {
    foo.setBar("def");
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do it? 
For example:

```
callIfNull(foo.getBar(), foo.setBar("def");
```

Comment: An if clause is already pretty simple.

Comment: you can use constructor injunction to do the same..

Answer (score 2):

Just declare it as

```
private String bar = "def";
```

If someone calls the setter, it will get overwritten, otherwise this will be the default value.

Comment: Just want to set value out of the class.

Comment: Parameterized constructor - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a **default constructor** in Java, and I always recommend using it. It is valuable to define a default value for all fields as something non-null. By defining your default constructors, you are declaring that the instance of a bean will be initialized in default way, with non-null features.

```
public class Bean {
  private int foo;
  private String bar;

  public Bean() {
    this(0, "");
  }

  public Bean(int foo, String bar) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
  }
...
// + getters and setters
```